# multiple cert in a file?

Tags: ssl, keytool

I have a file which contains:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(many lines of 64 bytes)
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I use `keytool.exe -printcert -file (myfile)`
it outputs like this

```
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=www.mydomain.xxxxxx  

(bah bah bah............)  
(bah bah bah............)  

Certificate[2]:
Owner: CN=Thawte SSL CA, O="Thawte, Inc.", C=US  

(bah bah bah............)  
(bah bah bah............)  

Certificate[3]:
Owner: CN=thawte Primary Root CA, OU="(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=Certification Services Division, O="thawte, Inc.", C=US  

(bah bah bah............)  
(bah bah bah............)
```

Is it normal that it contains 3 certs?
Is it called cert chain?
What can I do if I want to import this file to a `keystore`?
I've tried over and over again using

```
keytool.exe -import -alias (myalias) -trustcacerts -file (thisfile)  -keystore (mykeystore)`
```

but it keeps telling me

```
 java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate
```

Answer (score 1):

The `keytool` requires certificate chains to be provided in **PKCS#7** format (usually `.p7b` file extension) but you have it as a **PEM** file (which is rather used by software like *Apache*, *nginx* etc.).

From the [`keytool` manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) (`-importcert` option):

> -importcert:
>   Reads the certificate or certificate chain (*where the latter is supplied in a PKCS#7 formatted reply*) ...

---

To convert the file you can use the `openssl` utility (if you have it at hand):

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -certfile cert.pem -out cert.p7b -nocrl
```

Where `cert.pem` is your current certificate file and `cert.p7b` the one to use for the import.

Comment: I get error --> error reading the file, (my file).pem
error loading certificates
4700:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1304:
4700:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:380:Type=X509_CINF
4700:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:748:Field=cert_info, Type=X509
4700:error:0907400D:PEM routines:PEM_X509_INFO_read_bio:ASN1 lib:pem_info.c:256: